# Android different packageName with flavors

Tags: android, manifest, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I need to install 2 versions of my project (Production and Development). I need 2 apps. I'm trying to achive it by using flavors, but when I sign the apk, it always generate the same app, with the same packageName (com.company.project). I've tried removing the applicationId from the defaultConfig but it doesn't work neither.In the manifest, the package name is com.company.project.

Anyone knows how to do that?

This is the build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            applicationId "com.company.project"
    }    
    productFlavors {
                development {
                    applicationId
                    "com.company.project.DEV"
                    versionName "1.0-dev"
                    resValue "string", "app_name", "Project-Dev"                     
                }
                production {
                    applicationId
                    "com.company.project.PROD"
                    resValue "string", "app_name", "Project-Prod"
                    versionName "1.0-prod"                        
                }
            }
```

Comment: how are you building your separate APKs?  i.e. what is the command you use?  how are you confirming what the package name is after you build it?

Comment: @rothloup Gradle can make all what you need by default. Just create your projects in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it like this:

```
def appName = 'AppName'
productFlavors {
    devel {
        applicationIdSuffix ".devel"
        def buildId, appNameLabel
        buildId = androidApplicationId + '.devel' + androidVersionCode
        appNameLabel = appName + 'd' + androidVersionName
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_ID", '"' + buildId + '"'
        manifestPlaceholders = [app_name_label: appNameLabel, buildId: buildId]        }

    QA { 
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        def buildId, appNameLabel
        buildId = androidApplicationId + '.qa' + androidVersionCode
        appNameLabel = appName + 'q' + androidVersionName
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_ID", '"' + buildId + '"'
        manifestPlaceholders = [app_name_label: appNameLabel, buildId: buildId]
    }

    pro {
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_ID", '"' + androidApplicationId + '"'
        manifestPlaceholders = [app_name_label: appName, buildId: androidApplicationId]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create `productFlavors` then the corresponding `gradle` tasks also changes.

For instance, originally you have only `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease`. But, after implementing `productFlavors`, the `gradle` tasks will change. Taking your example in consideration, it will be

- `assembleDevelopmentDebug`
- `assembleDevelopmentRelease`
- `assembleProductionDebug`
- `assembleProductionRelease`

If you are using `Android Studio`, then you do not have to worry about the `gradle` tasks. Just select the `Build Variant` from the menu and build the project. It will run the corresponding gradle tasks and install the build.

I have written a blog explaining this, [Product Flavors in Android](http://android.pcsalt.com/product-flavors-android/). A sample project is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/product-flavours).

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a similar thing and my build.gradle looks like this and it works:

```
flavorDimensions 'Level'
productFlavors {
    alpha {
        dimension 'Level'
        applicationIdSuffix '.alpha'
    }
    beta {
        dimension 'Level'
        applicationIdSuffix '.beta'
    }
    major {
        dimension 'Level'
    }
}
```

I actually set this up in Build -> Edit Flavors and it generated everything for me.

Comment: I asked this 5 years ago and I forgot to auto answer this when I get to it, this is a good start, but for more complex projects, my answer is better, because it replaces package names in manifest